# Append data to multidimensional array (swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I'm having a problem with passing data in an multidimensional array.
So this is the Array:

```
var dataHome:[[String]] = []
```

And I would like to pass data into it like this:

```
if let countries_list = json as? NSArray
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < countries_list.count ; i++ )
            {
                if let country_obj = countries_list[i] as? NSDictionary
                {

                    println(country_obj)
                    let countryName = country_obj["country"] as! String
                    let countryCode = country_obj["code"] as! String
                    var tempArray:[String] = []
                    tempArray.append(countryName)
                    tempArray.append(countryCode)

                    println(tempArray)
                    dataHome.append(tempArray)
                    println(dataHome)


                }
            }
        }
```

It crashes when I try to pass data into `dataHome.append(tempArray)`

The array from country_obj is `{code = US;country = Amerika;}`

Does anybody have an solution ?

Thank's !

EDIT:

the whole function is:

```
func extract_json(data:NSString){

    var parseError: NSError?
    let jsonData:NSData = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
    let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &parseError)

    if (parseError == nil)
    {
        if let countries_list = json as? NSArray
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < countries_list.count ; i++ )
            {
                if let country_obj = countries_list[i] as? NSDictionary
                {

                    println(country_obj)
                    var countryName = country_obj["country"] as! String
                    var countryCode = country_obj["code"] as! String
                    println(countryName)
                    println(countryCode)
                    var tempArray:[String] = []
                    tempArray.append(countryName)
                    tempArray.append(countryCode)

                    println(tempArray)
                    dataHome.append(tempArray)
                    println(dataHome)


                }
            }
        }
    }
    do_table_refresh();
}
```

The error is: Thread 3: Breakpoint 2.1 
`tempArray.append(countryName)`

Comment: What is the exact error message? Does it really happen on this line or on one of the forced unwrapped optionals? Because your code looks ok... as long as you always have complete data, otherwise it will crash everytime countryName or countryCode is nil.

Comment: I just edited the post and added the error message and the complete function.

Comment: Look at the line numbers gutter in Xcode, to the left of the highlighted line. If there's a blue rectangle, remove it: it's a breakpoint. You may have set one accidentally.

Comment: Your'r right:D:D Thank's a lot guy !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "Thread 1: breakpoint 2.1"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038226/error-thread-1-breakpoint-2-1)